# TYPO3 deployment with SURF, issue with LocalConfiguration.php

Tags: typo3, fluid, extbase, surf

I am using TYPO3 SURF to deploy my application. I added "LocalConfiguration.php" to my .gitignore. So everytime I push and deploy, the config file is missing from the live server and I have to go through the install tool again. 
What is the best way to fix this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Include your `LocalConfiguration.php` in your versioning and deployment. Use a configuration switch to have different configuration values on different systems (e.g. development vs production). Here are some ways how to do it: [Good practices in TYPO3 projects #3 Use a configuration switch mechanism](https://usetypo3.com/good-practices-in-projects.html#c342)

Comment: I do not think this is a good idea, although it quickly solves the issue:
If you make changes in the install tool, the changes are written to the LocalConfiguration.php. The latest changes would be overwritten in the next deployment process.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to copy the LocalConfiguration.php file into your shared folder and create a symlink from your release folder to that file.
https://docs.typo3.org/other/typo3/surf/2.0/en-us/Examples/TYPO3/Index.html